# Swift 3 - Upload video file to facebook

Tags: swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, share

How i can share video file to facebook, from local directory.

```
let dataTs: Data?
```

I try use other solution but they not work

```
        var videoData: Data
        do {
            videoData = ServerManager.sharedManager.dataTs
            print(videoData)
            var strDesc : String
            strDesc = "test Description"
            let videoObject: [String : Any] = ["title": "Millions Poet", "description": strDesc]
            let uploadRequest: FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/videos", parameters: videoObject, httpMethod: "POST")
            uploadRequest.start(completionHandler: {(connection: FBSDKGraphRequestConnection, result: AnyObject, error: NSError) -> Void in
                if error == error {
                    NSLog("Error")
                } else {
                    NSLog("Success")
                }

                } as! FBSDKGraphRequestHandler)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Swift 3 code***

```
// Initialize like usual
    CRCloudRail.setAppKey("[YourLicenseKey]")

    // let social = Twitter(clientID: "[clientID]", clientSecret: "[clientSecret]")
    // let social = FacebookPage(pageName: "[pageName]", clientID: "[clientID]", clientSecret: "[clientSecret]")
    let social = Facebook(clientID: "[clientID]", clientSecret: "[clientSecret]")

    // Get the parameters
    let message = "I love CloudRail!!"
    let inputStream = // stream to video content
    let mime = "video/mp4"

    // Make the request
    social.postVideo(message: message, video: inputStream, size: 3242456, mimeType: mime)
```

Comment: they not understand CRCloudRail and Facebook(clientID: "[clientID]", clientSecret: "[clientSecret]")